# Why can't I stop my timer

Tags: c#, timer

I make a window form application , press the button to do the method every 5 minutes, and press again to stop doing it...but it keeps doing the method even when I call the stop method from the timer.

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);
t.AutoReset = true;
t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(my_method);
if (start == false)
{
    t.Start();
    start = true;
    Checkbutton.Text = "End";
}
else
{
    t.Stop();
    t.AutoReset = false;
    Checkbutton.Text = "Begin";
    MessageBox.Show("Auto Check Stop!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: Ain't you creating a new timer everytime on this function? Have Timer t as private variable of your class and move t= new Timer  stuff inside start == false condition; just before t.Start().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating a new `Timer` class instance on every click of the button which you have provided to your user to control the started/stopped status of the timer. **You should be instantiating it only once** inline while declaring it as member variable or inside the constructor of the form class. Then keep calling its Start/Stop API inside the button click event handler as shown in the code below to change it state based on the `start` flag value:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds);
        bool start == false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            t.AutoReset = true;
            t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(my_method);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (start == false)
            {
                t.Start();
                start = true;
                Checkbutton.Text = "End";
            }
            else
            {
                t.Stop();
                t.AutoReset = false;
                Checkbutton.Text = "Begin";
                MessageBox.Show("Auto Check Stop!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timer needs to be scoped outside the function. Move the first three lines outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because every time to execute the code in the question you get a *new* timer.

Presumably your code does this:

1. Construct a new timer
2. Since `start` is `true`, you start this timer
3. The next time you execute it, you construct a new timer (separate from the first)
4. Since `start`is `false` you ask this new timer to stop, but it was never started

If you want to stop the timer you started previously you need to store the reference to it so that you can access the *same* timer.

Typically you would store it in a field in the surrounding class. Also make sure you only construct the timer once.